# clearIterval variable not defined with setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I have the following code:

```js
var timer = 15;

$("body").on("keyup", function(event) {
  var tickerInterval = setInterval(clock_ticker, 1000);
});

function clock_ticker() {
  timer--;
  // Does a bunch of things

  console.log(timer);

  if(timer == 0) {
     clearInterval(tickerInterval);
  }
}
```

However, it gives me an error about `tickerInterval` not being defined. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @David I will update the question with more information. :)

Comment: because `var tickerInterval` is defined in the function and it is not accessible outside of that function! It is a basic scope problem.

Comment: @epascarello Isn't the variable inside a parent function? I thought that would make it accessible inside `clock_ticker` as well. Is that wrong?

Comment: No, there is no parent function.

Comment: @epascarello Isn't the callback I defined for `keyup` event considered a parent function?

Comment: just because a function calls another function, it does not get any of the local variables from that block scope.

Comment: `var tickerInterval; $("body").on("keyup", function(event) {
  if (!tickerInterval) { tickerInterval = setInterval(clock_ticker, 1000); }
});`

Comment: Thanks @epascarello :). I didn't use this part `if (!tickerInterval)` because it works without that as well. Just to be clear, I was defining the variable inside the `keyup` callback. and the `clock_ticker` function is also called within the same callback. So, why didn't it have access to the variable `tickerInterval`?

Comment: Isn't that the same thing as creating a variable in the global scope and then using it within a function we defined? If it is different, then how is it different?